# Free ASP.Net and/or CSS Themes

Tags: css, asp.net, themes

Where can I get some decent looking free ASP.Net or CSS themes?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I wouldn't bother looking for ASP.NET stuff specifically (probably won't find any anyways). Finding a good CSS theme easily can be used in ASP.NET.

Here's some sites that I love for CSS goodness:

http://www.freecsstemplates.org/
http://www.oswd.org/
http://www.openwebdesign.org/
http://www.styleshout.com/
http://www.freelayouts.com/

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft hired one fo the kids from A List Apart to whip some out. The .Net projects are free of charge for download.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336613.aspx

Comment: Link no longer avaialable

Answer (score 5):

I have used [Open source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/) in the past.  They have quite a few css themes, don't know about ASP.Net

Answer (score 3):

As always, http://www.csszengarden.com/. Note that the images aren't public domain.