# Theme in ASP.NET using framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, themes

Are there any predefined ASP.NET themes available for inside .net framework 4.0 or not?
If answer is positive where are they located to embed in my web-application?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there aren't any predefined themes. However, I have managed to locate a set of [example](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=157239) ASP.net themes from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) *but* this applies to Visual Studio 2008, other versions don't have the same link. It may give you a start but you're probably better off just creating your own, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288/free-asp-net-and-or-css-themes) question for a load of links to CSS theme sites for some inspiration.